# Altium hierarchical design assigning net to power port/port

Tags: power, altium, network, port

I have a hierachical multichannel design and I´m having problems to set properly the project properties so that the following issue is removed.
[image: child sheet with power port connected to port]

As you can see one of the ports of the child sheet is connected to the Vm_GND power port net.
Once recompiled the schematics I have found that when alt+click over this net, the other Vm_GND port of other schematic sheets in the design do not highlight.

When importing this design to PCB the I_SNS- net is not connected to Vm_GND in the PCB of so this is a major issue because as you can see it should be.

These are my project options:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I_SNS- is shown as an "output" port. Where is the matching "input" port to connect the other channels? I don't recommend using the "output" I/O Type for this, I suggest using "unspecified". I don't think multiple output ports will connect to one another without a matching "input" port, but this may not be the case with "unspecified".

Comment: Also, if power ports are global, why bother with the I_SNS- sheet port at all?

Comment: I_SNS- is an output port and it will be connected to an input port in another child sheet.

Comment: On the other hand, I think that the problem comes when connecting a port to a power port this way. Altium compiler has to decide wether to use the global power port or the output port (I_SNS- in this case). If Altium assigns ISNS- net then it cannot be connected to the global power port. But I thought that using "Power port names take priority" would solve this type of problems. Maybe a Net Tie should be used in this case...

Comment: Then you did not provide enough information to answer your question. You should show all pertinent schematics related to your question. Anyway, I still see no need for the "I_SNS-" port if the "Vm_GND" port is global.

Comment: I need this net to be named different than Vm_GND but still connected to Vm_GND. I think Net Tie would do the trick...

Comment: A global net either is, or it isn't.  By connecting a global power symbol to a port, you're reducing its scope to a local net.  Either get rid of the port, and keep Vm_GND global, or get rid of the Vm_GND symbol, and use local nets via ports.  Or add a level of complexity, and un-manageability, by using net ties.

Comment: I agree with Chris on this. To me it makes more sense to get rid of the I_SNS- port because it is much easier to keep track of global power ports (Vm_GND)

Comment: Yes, I do also prefer not to use net Ties. So if I would need to take part of a global net and name it differently how would you do that without a net tie?

Comment: @user6127833 Don't try to rename Vm_GND. Just leave it as-is and delete the port. Then anywhere you originally had I_SNS- just put a copy of the Vm_GND power port.

Comment: Mmmm, but this would imply that, if for example, routing this part of the global net that needs to be routed independently from the global net (a plane in this case) but still connected to it, any via added to the routing would be directly connected to the plane. And I don´t want to. This is just an example of a possible case. Maybe the only solution is to take care this doen´t happen in the PCB but there will be no automatic DRC or error message when some of these problems happen...

Comment: On the other, hand. Why, if the option of "Power port names take priority" is checked is this power port reduced to local?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to use Kelvin connections so that your sense traces don't carry any current.  To do this best in Altium, use a "net tie" component.  It allows you to connect two nets together at a specific point on the PCB.  Google "Net tie" and Altium and you should be able to find what you need.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the tip. I indeed need this type of connection so, as I thought, net tie is to be used. Nonetheless I particularly hate net ties so that's the reason why I connected this circuit this way.